# Write the following functions in simplest form.

Tags: trigonometry, functions, inverse

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)$$

Hi,
      I am not able to solve this problem from last 1 hour. Please help me to solve this question.
    As I can solve simple inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: Set $x = a \sin(\phi)$, and simplify the argument of the $\arctan$. Are you assuming $0<x<a$?

Answer (score 5):

Think geometrically. What is the $\tan(\phi)$ ?

[image]

Comment: Please, can you tell me the name of the software which you use to draw these pictures. I try to use GeoGebra and a friend recommend me to use MetaPost but I have some issues to use these software correctly. Thanks :)

Comment: @Iuli I used [_Mathematica_](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The command can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19Is-ofRbRPBMNOI6kdbAOA9XR-uouUqEzEcy7OcIUIM/edit).

Comment: So $\arctan\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arccos\dfrac x a$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think it should be $\arcsin \frac{x}{a}$, instead.

Comment: @Sasha : You're right: I'm accustomed to pictures in which the "opposite" side is vertical and the "adjacent" side horizontal.